# Combining base url with resultant href in scrapy

Tags: python, url, scrapy

below is my spider code,

```
class Blurb2Spider(BaseSpider):
   name = "blurb2"
   allowed_domains = ["www.domain.com"]

   def start_requests(self):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.domain.com/bookstore/new")


   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       urls = hxs.select('//div[@class="bookListingBookTitle"]/a/@href').extract()
       for i in urls:
           yield Request(urlparse.urljoin('www.domain.com/', i[1:]),callback=self.parse_url)


   def parse_url(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       print response,'------->'
```

Here i am trying to combine the href link with the base link , but i am getting the following error ,

```
exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: www.domain.com//bookstore/detail/3271993?alt=Something+I+Had+To+Do
```

Can anyone let me know why i am getting this error and how to join base url with href link and yield a request

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because you didn't add the scheme, eg http:// in your base url.

Try: `urlparse.urljoin('http://www.domain.com/', i[1:])`

Or even more easy: `urlparse.urljoin(response.url, i[1:])` as urlparse.urljoin will sort out the base URL itself.

Comment: And at the same time can u tell me the difference between urlparse and urljoin because by using any one of them too i am able to get the answer

Comment: Both methods urlparse.urlparse and urlparse.urljoin are part of the urlparse module. See also: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

Comment: What else were you importing here?  I run similar code and get the error  exceptions.NameError: global name 'Request' is not defined

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, haven't had the time to login. @Mittenchops: `from scrapy.http import Request`

Answer (score 23):

An alternative solution, if you don't want to use `urlparse`:

```
response.urljoin(i[1:])
```

This solution goes even a step further: here Scrapy works out the domain base for joining. And as you can see, you don't have to provide the obvious `http://www.example.com` for joining.

This makes your code **reusable** in the future if you want to change the domain you are crawling.

Comment: This is cleaner than `urlparse`

Answer (score 4):

The best way to follow a link in `scrapy` is to use `response.follow()`. scrapy will handle the rest.

[more info](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests)

Quote from docs:

> Unlike `scrapy.Request`, `response.follow` supports relative URLs directly - no need to call `urljoin`.

Also, you can pass `<a>` element directly as argument.