# Getting error with yield in scrapy python

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this code. When i am using yyield to request futher link then i get this errror

```
Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'dict'
```

I have tried verything but i can't get rid of error

Code is here

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("//li[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' mod-searchresult-entry ')]")
    items = []


    for site in sites[:2]:

        item = SeekItem()
        item['title'] = myfilter(site.select('dl/dd/h2/a').select("string()").extract())
        item['link_url'] = myfilter(site.select('dl/dd/h2/em').select("string()").extract())
        item['description'] = myfilter(site.select('dl/dd/p').select("string()").extract())
        if  item['link_url']:
                      yield Request(urljoin('http://www.seek.com.au/', item['link_url']),
                      meta = item,
                      callback = self.parseItemDescription)

        yield item

def parseItemDescription(self, response):

    item = response.meta
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("//li[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' mod-searchresult-entry ')]")
    item['description'] = "mytest"

    return item
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of scrapy are you using. The documentation for 0.16.2 has this method of [passing items to another callback](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.16/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions).

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("//li[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' mod-searchresult-entry ')]")
    items = []

    for site in sites[:2]:
        item = SeekItem()
        item['title'] = myfilter(site.select('dl/dd/h2/a').select("string()").extract())
        item['link_url'] = myfilter(site.select('dl/dd/h2/em').select("string()").extract())
        item['description'] = myfilter(site.select('dl/dd/p').select("string()").extract())
        if item['link_url']:
            request = Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html", callback=self.parseItemDescription)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            return request

def parseItemDescription(self, response):

    item = response.meta['item']
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("//li[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' mod-searchresult-entry ')]")
    item['description'] = "mytest"

    return item
```

NB: this is untested as the rest of your code (spider, items.py etc) is missing and I'm not sure how this is being run

Answer (score 3):

## Two yields

You're yielding twice - the first time is a **Request**; the second is a **dic**. (*yield Request(...)* and *yield item*)

I'm guessing the second time is unnecessary and should be removed. Try that and comment below. (remove the line that says *yield item*)

Comment: Also, what's up with that extra parenthesis after _self.parseItemDescription_?

Comment: ok. when i removed teh `yield item` then it don't work but when i remove the second `return item` then it worked. but then my description is not getting inserted in the items. the second bracket is of the Request() and it is working fine

Comment: Do you mean to call _parseItemDescription_ on some response? You have _self.parseItemDescription_, without any parentheses to call the function - why would you do that?

Comment: it has been working fine like that , i think its a callback. like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798118/combining-base-url-with-resultant-href-in-scrapy

Comment: In the question you linked to, there was no return on the callback function. Is that the problem?

Comment: i told earlier if i remove the return from callback function , then it works but then i don't get description